# Jquery mobile autofocus does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need add autofocus for my mobile site for That I have used

```
`<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#div_error").focus();
        });



</script >`
```

but this does not work. what is the reason for that?

```
<div  id="div_error" tabindex="-1">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Document ready`** can't be used in this manner with jQuery Mobile.

While it will trigger it will trigger before jQuery Mobile can create and style active page.
To counter this correct jQuery Mobile page event must be used. If you don't know what page jQuery Mobile events are then take a look at my **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/D9NBT/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div  id="div_error" tabindex="-1">some text</div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $("#div_error").focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this will not work for me. it focus to div tag very few mill second and again load page as normal

Comment: Then you have an error somewhere in your code. This example works live and in jsFiddle. Can you post whole page HTML? Or do you have a live example?